# PHP remove superfluous arrays from arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Having a bit of a brainfart here, I've got an array that looks like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 'fruit' => 'orange', ) 
[1] => Array ( 'fruit' => 'apple', )
)
```

annnnnnnnd it's got to end up like this:

```
Array ( 
[0] => 'orange'
[1] => 'apple' 
)
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_shift`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

```
$array = array_map('array_shift', $array);
```

or just loop over it:

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
    $array[$key] = array_shift($value);
}
```

**Update:** Using `array_shift` is much better if you always want to get the first value or if the subarrays contain only one value anyway...

If you have a more complicated structure, e.g. more elements in the subarrays, then you basically want to [*flatten your array*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1319903/how-to-flatten-a-multidimensional-array).

Comment: @onoe: And my solution did not work? `reset` and `array_shift` are doing the same thing in a way. `array_shift` is more self-explanatory than `reset`.

Answer (score 0):

If the key isn't always the same (i.e. if it isn't always fruit), you could do this:

```
<?php
$source = array( 
    0 => array ( 'fruit' => 'orange', ) 
    1 => array ( 'fruit' => 'apple', )
);     

$destination = array();

foreach($source as $source_array)
{
    foreach($source_array as $value)
    {
        $destination[] = $value;
    }
}
?>
```